# Why would tellp() be a non-const?

Tags: c++, constants, stringstream, seek

I am working on a logger which has a message inheriting `std::stringstream`.

At the point when I want to print out the message, I call a function which accepts the message as a `const`:

```
void logger::log_message(message const & msg)
```

In that function, I want to check whether anything was written to the message. If not, I can just ignore the call. I use the following:

```
if(const_cast<message &>(msg).tellp() == 0)
{
    return;
}
```

I had to use the `const_cast<>()` because `tellp()` is not `const`. What I'm wondering is why would retrieving the current seek position have side effects on the stream. I could understand the `seekp()` which changes the position, but not the `tellp()`. Could that be a mistake in the specs?

Comment: `std::stringstream` -- and what if the stream is not a `std::stringstream`, but some other type of stream that does need to update the state for some reason?  I guess the standards committee didn't want to restrict what a stream can do when returning a position.

Comment: As seen here: https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/comments/91jbd4/why_is_stdostreamtellp_nonconst/. The tellp function will change the value of rdstate if failed. You can also see that it change the state in this cpprefference page: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UnformattedOutputFunction

Comment: @EnoshCohen Now that makes sense. It is rare that people check for error on a `seek()` anyway... (even though we all should)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tellp()` will change the `rdstate` of the object if it fails.

See:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UnformattedOutputFunction